# Python passing a method to another method

Tags: python, python-3.x, method-call

What i'm trying to do is create a time polling method/mechanism, which as input recieves a method it needs to run inside the time loop (from other modules\classes and might or might not have input params itself) , exit condition (True/False/String/Int) and the timeout
This is what i've created

```
def time_polling(polled_method,exit_condition,timer):
   elapsed_time = 0
   sleep_period = 10
   while elapsed_time<=int(timer):
      if polled_method == exit_condition:
         return True
      time.sleep(sleep_period)
      elapsed_time+=sleep_period
   return False
```

the way i call it is like this  :

```
timed_polling(lambda: validation_installation.ValidationInstallation.check_installed_product(),True,60)
```

The problem is that if i call the method without the lambda , then obviously the call is made inside the call command , with the lambda it seems that the method is not being called inside the timed_polling method.
What am I missing?

Comment: `if polled_method() == exit_condition:` and you don't need the lambda if you remove the parentheses when passing the function

Comment: Btw, `lambda: something.foo.bar()` should probably just be `something.foo.bar`, in the sense that `lambda : foo()` is equivalent to passing `foo`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why so complex ? No need for lambda.

```
timed_polling(lambda: validation_installation.ValidationInstallation.check_installed_product(),True,60)
```

should be just

```
# note: no parentheses, pass function object itself
timed_polling(validation_installation.ValidationInstallation.check_installed_product,True,60)
```

then in the code this is wrong as `polled_method` is a method, and it needs to be called *now* so:

```
  if polled_method == exit_condition:
     return True
```

should be (added () to call it):

```
  if polled_method() == exit_condition:
     return True
```

else the method is not called